# Where to store a Doctrine variable created in a component so that it's accessible anywhere?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Note I am referring to one request, and not several requests and sessions.

I have several components that require Doctrine user object, some are located in layout, others are located in templates. Sometimes I need that Doctrine user object in action. Currently I have added a function to sfUser class that loads that object from database, which means every time I call that function I make a call to db. I'd like to know where to store this object so that I can access it without having to query db every time I need it. Again, we're talking about a single request, not several requests or something that would require session.

Can I save it in sfContext somehow? Any other places so that it can be available everywhere?

Comment: You shouldn't store it in sfContext, because it doesn't make any semantical sense (sfContext represents Controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in your model's Table class, because tables are always accessed as singletones.

```
class sfGuardUserTable extends PluginsfGuardUserTable
{
  protected $specialUser = null;

  public function getSpecialUser()
  {
    if (null === $this->specialUser)
    {
      $this->specialUser = $this->findOneById(1);
    }
    return $this->specialUser;
  }
}
```

Now, you can use this in actions and components like this:

```
$u = sfGuardUserTable::getInstance()->getSpecialUser();
```

And you will always end up with one query.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure [Doctrine cache](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/caching%3aquery-cache-&-result-cache) so that the result of this specific request is always cached. What if so good about it is that if you use, say, the APC backend, you will have it cached **across requests**. You also get **query** caching as a bonus (this is not **result** caching, read the link I provided carefully)!